# Numbers printing alphabetical order

Tags: python

I need these numbers to print ascending order,( like 1,2,3,4,5), but they are printing in alphabetical order.

```
numberList = [ ]

with open('Numbers.txt','r') as file:   
    for line in file:         
        for word in line.split():
            numberList.append(word)
            numberList.sort()
file = open("Numbers.txt")
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What does your input look like? Please update your question with some example input and some expected example output. Maybe also read [ask], to identify yourself with the proper ways to ask solid questions! :-)

Comment: What exactly you want. Ascending order means they will print in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your for loops you could use a function called map along with sorted.

```
numberList = sorted(list(map(int,numberList)))
```

This would convert any string(that is a digit) into a integer in your list already created with all the items, and sort it right away.

Also, it would avoid you to keep sorting all the time.

```
numberList = [ ]

with open('Numbers.txt','r') as file:   
    for line in file:         
        for word in line.split():
            numberList.append(word)

numberList = sorted(list(map(int,numberList)))
file = open("Numbers.txt")
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with number, you should convert them to int

```
numberList = [ ]

with open('Numbers.txt','r') as file:   
    for line in file:         
        for word in line.split():
            numberList.append(int(word))

numberList.sort()
```